# beautifulsoup in python3.4 cannot use in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu14.0LTS and pycharm IDE how to download and install beautifulsoup and add beautifulsoup library into pycharm.

I tried using pip install it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install beautifulsoup4` does not work?

Did you try to create a new virtualenv in pycharm and simple add library?

Answer (score -1):

THis is how I found it,

**First** I click on file in the top menu.

**then** I click on settings, now look  for `project interpreter` this where you can add beautifulsoup by clicking on the green cross on the right site of the screen.

After installing it. Call it by using : `from bs4 import beautifulsoup`